# Django Designing Model : Item/Inventory/User

Tags: python, django, api, models

I would like to ask some advice on Modeling a specific model behavior.
Basically I have a model Item. It describes the name and description of an item.

I have a inventory, which should hold a "List" of items, considering the quantity of each item should be specified in the inventory.

Each `User` should have one unique inventory.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    invetory =models.ForeignKey(inventory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class item(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    value = models.FloatField()

class inventory(models.Model):
?
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use many-to-many relations. First of all you should delete the FK from the User model. Then create a separate model for items and finally link many users to many items (one user can handle multiple items and one item can belong to multiple users). Something like that:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class item(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=40)


class inventory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(item, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

PS Class names should use PascalCase convention https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#class-names

Comment: Thanks that´s exactly what wanted. I´m aware this class naming convention, I just typed for the question, Ididn´t noticed that.

Comment: Your model would allow a `User` to have more than one `Inventory`, change the user `ForeignKey` to be a `OneToOneField`. I would also add the Meta option [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to the `user` and `item` fields so you don't end up with duplicate items added to a user's inventory.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Inventory(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    value = models.FloatField()
    invetory =models.ForeignKey(Inventory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This should work as per your specification. We have tied up inventory to a user and each item will have a foreign key to Inventory table.

Now you can do

```
1. To access inventory you can do `user.inventory`
2. To get a list of items `user.inventory.item_set` 
3. You should use the `post_save` signal to create the inventory object.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class inventory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=User.objects.first())
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, default=Item.objects.first())
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I think this would make a better design.

Comment: How are we going to guarantee single inventory, this looks to be like of collection of user and item pairs? Maybe we should override `save` method.