# Django, when trying to associate items to inventory as inline it raises migration error

Tags: python, django, database

Purpose:
I want to make it possible to have inlines in inventory, so you can look up one specific user in the inventory model and modify their items.

In "Items", I want to be able to make items. They have a name and a price. Simple.

In "Inventory", I want to be able to make inventories, select a user (who owns it), and give them multiple items, using inlines. For the items, I want them to be independent: so if I make "Item 1", I want to be able to give "Item 1" to any inventory and I want them (the items) to be listed in the inventory, not in the items themselves.

For example:
Inventory

| user | items |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | item1,item2,item3 |
| user2 | item2,item6,item78 |

instead of:

Item

| belongs_to | item |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | item1 |
| user1 | item2 |
| user1 | item3 |
| user2 | item2 |
| user2 | item6 |
| user2 | item78 |

The error code:

```
<class 'core.admin.ItemInline'>: (admin.E202) 'core.Item' has no ForeignKey to 'core.Inventory'.
```

My code:

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, unique=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], default=0, help_text="0 means Free")

class Inventory(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, verbose_name="Belongs to")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, verbose_name="Item")
```

admin.py

```
class ItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Item
    extra = 0

class InventoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user']
    raw_id_fields = ['user']
    inlines = [ItemInline]

admin.site.register(Inventory, InventoryAdmin)
```

I already looked up these topics/questions, but (seemingly) none solved my problem.

[Inline in Django admin: has no ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899523/inline-in-django-admin-has-no-foreignkey)

[Django Designing Model : Item/Inventory/User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142123/django-designing-model-item-inventory-user)

[How to add multiple input from one field in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942448/how-to-add-multiple-input-from-one-field-in-django-model)

[Django - Submitting form with multiple inputs for same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469063/django-submitting-form-with-multiple-inputs-for-same-field)

Comment: Seems like you want to have multiple Items related to each Inventory and not the other way round, your models currently have multiple Inventories for each Item

Comment: Something like that, yes. How could I reverse this?

Comment: Remove the `Inventory.item` ForeignKey and create an `Item.inventory` ForeignKey, the relationship needs to be reversed

Comment: It would be fine, but if I do that, I have to make new Items (it asks you to give a name and a price), not select premade ones.

Comment: I want to make it similar to when you use "raw_id_fields", so you can select the item you want and then add more if needed.

Comment: I see, so each Item could be associated to multiple inventories? Use a ManyToManyField instead, something like `items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)` on the Inventory model

Comment: I like that one more. Is there a way to change this multiple selection? Like in the Groups model's permissions row, it has 2 selects called "Available permissions" and Chosen permissions". So you could move the wanted items, instead ctrl + clicking them and accidentally unclick one?

Comment: Pass the field to `filter_horizontal` in your ModelAdmin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal

Comment: Also it works if you only want to give the user one of the item, like an achievement, but if you want to give them more, like 3 keys, 5 papers, etc, you couldn't do that. That's where inlines could come in handy, where you add +1, select the item you want to give the user and type in the quantity. That's the thing I have no idea how to do, and I'm not sure if I could do it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question and I found it by trying to answer someone else's question. My solution can be found right there:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965110/13698713